# Oracle SQL fuzzy search for words in a varchar column

Tags: sql, oracle

We have an `Address` table with a lot of columns.

Example schema

**Address:**

```
Id | ADDR_LN1      | ADDR_LN2  | ADDR_LN3
---------------------------------------
1  | 3330 Scott st | Suite 300 | Houston TX 77058
```

The user searches for text say using 3 input fields:

```
Textinput1: 3330 Scott Street
Textinput2: Room 300  //
Textinput3: Houston tx
```

For the user this is a correct format and he starts searching for what he needs. How do I use the select statement so that it returns the row that is available in the DB?

I've tried similar to following (**Consider case insensitive for now**) but does not seem right at the performance point of view. Could some one point me to the right direction?

```
select  * 
    from address addr 
    where addr.addr_ln1 like '%3330 Scott street%'
        and (
            addr.addr_ln2 like '%room 300%' 
            or addr.addr_ln2 like '%300%'
        )
        and addr.addr_ln3 like '%houston tx%'
```

Comment: it'd never match, because `street` does not occur in your DB.  `like '%3330 Scott st%'` would work, though.

Comment: @MarcB Yes, my question is, is there a way for oracle to find out if it matches atleast 1 word?

Comment: change it to an `or` instead of `and`?

Comment: @MarcB Yeah that is a good point. Requirement is, each user input should be approximate to what is in the db. Meaning the textinput1 value should match a few words in the addr_ln1 column. eg: for us 3330 Scott matches (street can be ignored)

Comment: you'd probably be better off with a fulltext-type index, or whatever oracle's equivalent is. `like` comparisons are very inefficient, especially when you're doing pre-wildcards, `like '%foo'` cannot use indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The oft neglected Oracle SOUNDEX function might be worth a try for "fuzzy"(ish) matching. I have used Oracle Text/InterMedia (CTXSYS), to enable searching PDF/DOC files stored in BLOBs. So again, there might be scope there, whereby you hold a column CLOB which is all the text concatenated (trigger maintained?), then index this via CTXSYS, then you'll be able to use the CONTAINS command in the WHERE clause. See the link below to help get you started:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28303/quicktour.htm#i1008390

Warning though, since the search relies on the index being up to date, we found the only reliable way to ensure it was was to run the ctxsys.ctx_ddl.sync_index when the document was uploaded as part of the transaction.

Comment: Can this CTXRULE index be applied on multiple columns of the table?

Comment: I haven't tried that, but my first stab at this would be to maintain to "search" column and CTX index that to see if it will work as you wish, then start to push the boundaries and see if it will handle multiple columns. However, with >1 column you will be back to the same problem as you have with LIKE/OR, i.e. more complex querying.